# when i type CountDownTimer it not accepting

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
 }.start();
```

Comment: what do you mean by not accepting ?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol CountDownTimer

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: When i ask some question some people give me down vote whereas some people give me correct answer and understand my question correctly. Why they gave me down vote to ask question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've any of Android platform jar(`android.jar`) as in External Libraries you can import `android.os.CountDownTimer` in your class.

After import you can create object of CountDownTimer in your class:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `android.os.CountDownTimer`.

**Try this:**

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        .....................
        ..............................

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mTextField.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();

        .....................
        ..............................
    }
}
```